# How to duplicate a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I'd like to create a replica of a Document Library with 3000 items and several extra columns (meta data).

I know that I can save the Document Library as a template but due to the size I cannot save the contents.

Any guidelines?

Gracias!

Comment: Do you want to duplicate the library in same site?

Comment: Yes, in the same site

Comment: Check this solution (It is using CSOM): http://jenkinsblogs.com/2016/07/27/clone-or-copy-sharepoint-document-library-files-and-folders-from-one-site-to-another-using-csom/

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to copy the library in same site? maybe we can suggest any alternate approach to your requirements.

Comment: Because I have PowerApps App using the Library. I want to create an DEV environment to make some tests

Comment: Unfortunately CSOM is not allowed in our Tenant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can
1. Save library as template without the items. 
2. Create new library based on that template. 
3. Copy some of the items from original to new one (presumably for dev you don't need all items)